# mysql with many tables

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a major problem getting this to work properly. Here is the deal.

I have 4 tables - `timeline`, `connections`, `images`, `votes`

**Timeline table:**

```
time_id
time_title
```

etc.

The timeline table connects with the images table via the connections table

**Connections table:**

```
time_id
image_id
```

So the connections hold information about the id of the "post" the timeline and about image id

**Images table:**

```
image_id
image_url
image_type
```

Images table contains images that could be used in the same timeline(post), so by this i can see the connection by looking at the connection table.

I also have a votes table that holds information about votes for the specific timeline post

**Votes table:**

```
vote_id
time_id
```

the votes table contains many rows of each time_id and the idea is to count the number of times to se wich is the most popular

So heres the question:
I need to get the 5 most voted time_titles and show them with the first image for each time_title(post) so that it look like this for example

- Image 1 that corresponds to Title 1 - that is the highest voted
- Image 2 that corresponds to Title 2 - that is the second highest voted

etc.

Each timeline row (post) can hold many images and i only want to show the first of each post.

Hope you understand my problem!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This isn't IM, you don't have to put every sentence in its own line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query will be

```
SELECT
 count(v.vote_id) as vote_times
 t.time_title,
 ( 
  SELECT
   image_url
  FROM
   images 
  WHERE
   image_id = (
       SELECT
        image_id
       FROM
        connections as c
       WHERE
        c.time_id = t.time_id
       LIMIT 1
      )
  LIMIT 1
 ) as image_url
FROM
 votes as v
  LEFT JOIN
   time as t 
    on 
     t.time_id = v.time_id
GROUP BY
 v.time_id
ORDER BY
 vote_times desc
LIMIT 5;
```

This will work, but might not be the most optimized one.

-- EDIT
to get image_type also try

```
SELECT
    count(v.vote_id) as vote_times
    t.time_title,
 i.image_url,
 i.image_type

FROM
    votes as v
        LEFT JOIN
            time as t 
                on 
                    t.time_id = v.time_id
  LEFT JOIN
   images as i
    on
     i.image_id = (
         SELECT
          image_id
         FROM
          connections as c
         WHERE
          c.time_id = t.time_id
         LIMIT 1
        )
GROUP BY
    v.time_id
ORDER BY
    vote_times desc, image_type desc
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Thanks i million times! Its working great! 
Can I add another question... :) 
In my image table I have a type column that shows the type of image how would I add that i the statement so I could reach that information for sorting? Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: hey tobias, i have added the condition too.. and show your appreciation by up voting and selecting as correct answer(if its is correct that is). that is not just for this question, but for all your questions.

Comment: Once again thanks so much! its working like a charm with the edit too! thanks a lot, relly!!

Comment: Hi again! I came up with another dilemma... If i wanted to fetch all images for one specific time event without thinking of the voting - just using timeline table image table and connections table how could that look!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  t.time_title, i.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  t.time_title
        FROM    timeline t
        LEFT JOIN
                votes v
        ON      v.time_id = t.time_id
        GROUP BY
                t.id
        ORDER BY
                COUNT(vote_id) DESC, t.time_id DESC
        LIMIT 5
        ) t
JOIN    images i
ON      i.id = 
        (
        SELECT  ii.image_id
        FROM    connections c
        JOIN    image ii
        ON      ii.image_id = c.image_id
        WHERE   c.time_id = t.time_id
        ORDER BY
                ii.id DESC -- or whatever order you define for the "first" image
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Comment: `WHERE ii.time_id = t.id` images table dont have `time_id`, its in the connection table.